# I can't launch the application on TomEE

Tags: java, web, tomcat, apache-tomee

Earlier I used a regular Tomcat version 10.1.11, but then I switched to Tomee plus version 9.1.0 and everything stopped working for me. Now the page where the servlet should be displayed constantly throws the error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".
But if I run this application again through the regular version of Tomcat, then everything will work. Has anyone encountered such an error?

Comment: There is no TomEE 10.272.

Comment: sorry, translator made some mistakes. i have edited @BasilBourque

Comment: @VsevolodKasatchikov As rzo1 mentioned, there is no TomEE version 10.x.  The latest version is 9.1

Comment: @DavidBlevins oh, im sorry. i said like it was written in intellij idea. by fact, its 9.1.0 version

Comment: You should check catalina.out for any errors. Are you targeting EE10 or EE9.1 ?

Comment: @rzo1 i use EE9.1. there is only one warning in catalina.out: WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager.init You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping.
I dont think it matters so much

Answer (score 0):

TomEE usually keeps track of what's happening in log files. Look for any error messages or weird stuff in files like **catalina.out** or tomee.log.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).